# How to grab a link url from a stream

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, adobe-flash

Lets say I'm paying for a membership to watch educational stream that are live every day at 8pm. I want to end my membership in the future because its over priced. Is there a way I can grab a link within the stream so I do not have to sign in the membership portal?

The stream is posted on the same sight and url every time. For example, with videos that are not streamed, I can use google chrome and use the "inspect tool" and find that link so I can visit that link whenever I want without having to sign in to a portal. Can I do the same with streams?

Can I have a link I can visit at 8pm everyday and watch the stream without signing into a membership portal?

Comment: Stream uses Adobe Flash 24.0.0.194 on Chrome OS

Comment: If the link is same every time, what stops you from bookmarking this link in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

1. We're not here to help you pirate material.
2. Any site worth it's salt will be using unique signed URLs, which are timed as well, before redirecting you to a viewing URL. This is why you can't send the URL you're using to watch media on this site to a friend.
3. If anyone finds away around this, there's a good chance they're a security researcher or pentester. If that's the case, they're going to tell the hosting site about the exploit, and not someone trying to steal it.

Comment: Pretty much this. If it's worth it - then shell out the extra cash - if you can't afford it then perhaps another avenue of material may be in your future.